# Need clarification regarding a few definitions and notations of the paper

Tags: general-topology, ideals, intuition, filters

Started reading [this paper by Das & Savas.](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-5180/2013/0354-51801301089D.pdf) A few definitions are new I need to have them clear. So here are those $4$ definitions and I've put down my own assessments. Kindly tell me if those are correct and if not what went wrong and what the right meaning would be. Thanks.

$1)$At one point it defines

Every Linear Topology $\tau$ on a vector space $L$ has a base $N$ for the **neighbourhoods of $\theta$** satisfying the following properties:

**a)** Each $V ∈ N$ is a balanced set, that is $λx ∈ V$ holds for all $x ∈ V$ and every $λ ∈ \mathbb R$ with $|λ| ≤ 1$
.
**b)** Each $V ∈ N$ is an absorbing set, that is for every $x ∈ L$, there exists a $λ > 0$ such that $λx ∈ V$
.
**c)** For each $V ∈ N$ there exists some $W ∈ N$ with $W + W ⊂ V$.

Then next at Definition $2.2$  it says :

A Linear Topology $\tau$ on a Reisz Space $L$  is said to be lically solid if $\tau $ has a base **at zero** consisting of solid sets.

I think **zero** and $\theta$  are the same point for this linear topological space and the terms are interchangeable right?

The next things are the definitions $D_{\alpha},F_0,I_0.$

$2)$For a fixed $\alpha\in D; D_{\alpha}=\{\beta\in D:\beta\ge \alpha\}$

Then,is it valid to say that the set $D_{\alpha}$ is *bounded below by $'\alpha'$?*

$3)$ $$F_0=\{A\subset D:A\supset D_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha\in D\}.$$
I'm guessing this $F_0$ is actually a collection of subsets of $D$ that are **unbounded above and bounded below.** That is, all the the subsets of $D$ that start from some $\alpha\in D$ and goes all the way up,are the members of $F_0.$ But then $D\supset D_\alpha$ is true for all $\alpha.$ So $D\in F_0 ?$

$4)$ $$I_0=\{A\subset D:A^c\in F_0\}\\=\{A\subset D: A^c\supset D_\alpha \text{ for some } \alpha\in D\}\\ \{A\subset D:A\subset D_\alpha^c\}\\=\{A\subset D: A=\{\gamma\in D:\gamma \le \alpha\}\text{ for some } \alpha\in D\}$$  So, is it safe to say $I_0$ is the set of all **bounded above unbounded below** subsets of $D?$

$5)$ **Definition $2.3$**: A net $\{s_α : α ∈ D\}$ in a topological space $(X, τ)$ is said to be $I$-convergent to $x_0 ∈ X$ if for any
open set $U$ containing $x_0, \{α ∈ D : s_α < U\} ∈ I$.

Why using this strange notation $ s_α < U\ ?$ Apparently it means the same as $s_\alpha \notin U$  but what is the significance of writing it as $ s_α < U?$

These are from the second page of the paper from definitions $2.1,2.2$ and $2.3$

Answer (score 1):

1) I'm pretty sure that by linear topological space, they mean topological vector space, and if so, then I suspect by 'base at zero', they mean that the topology has neighborhood basis at the zero vector.

2) $D_{\alpha}$ is the filter of $\alpha$ in $D$.

3) $F_0$ is the principal filter of $D_{\alpha}$ in $D$.

4) $I_0$ is principal ideal of $D_{\alpha}$ in $D$. (ideals are the dual notion to that of filters)

You may find this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know $D_\alpha,F_0$ are filters and $I_0$ is ideal. But when you say sete of all filters , does not that mean every member of $F_0$ is a filter ? But the members are merely subsets.

Comment: You're right that it's not the set of all filters/ideals. Looking at it more closely, $\alpha$ is a fixed element of $D$ here. So it stands to reason that $F_0$ is actually the filter of $D_{\alpha}$ as an element of $\mathcal{P}(D)$, and thus $I_0$ is the corresponding ideal.

Comment: OK.But  I need to know whether the phrases that I'm using , like, **bounded above** or **unbounded above**  are acceptable. And why use $s_a \lt U$ instead of $s_a\notin U.$

Comment: I would avoid the bounded/unbounded language because it does not capture the full generality of the situation with filters and ideals.